# how to have Drop down filter at header in aspx gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

How can i have drop down on header filter option for one column in my aspx grid ?
Can i use "GridViewDataComboBoxColumn" for header filter drop down ? Or there is some other way of doing it ?
I am using the older version of devExpress (version 8.2) and i can not find option of following in settings

```
showHeaderFilterButton
```

I can show drop down in filter header using GridViewDataComboBoxColumn but i think it is used for updating/editing any particular row that matches value from drop down.

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Thanks..
Anjum